# Loft doesn't follow guide curve as intended in Solidworks v22

Tags: solidworks

I have been trying to make a surface loft of a pipe that goes around a U-turn and gradually changes diameter.

I was finally able to complete the surface loft, but something is off in the result. My profile and guide curves are shown below. As you can see, the **profiles** are gradually spaced circles coincident to the **guide** U-curve. It is hard to see in this image, but when I zoom in on the larger diameter pipe, you can see that it is no longer straight like the guide curve.

I've highlighted the portions with low curvature, and while this is a problem, there is a portion on the opposite side with very high curvature. How do I ensure this surface loft in the straight portions of the **guide** is also straight?

I'm using Solidworks v.22.

[image: curves]
[image: problem_loft]

Comment: The simple answer to this, is add more guide curves.

Comment: For this specific shape, however, it might be more effective to model the tapered tube in its unbent state using a revolve, and then use the Flex feature to bend it around

Comment: I wasn't aware I could add more than one guide curve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the shape that you are attempting to create - it would be more effective to model the tapered tube in its unbent state using a revolve, and then use the Flex feature to bend it around.

[image: Finished Item]

Comment: What is the flex tool? And did you simply make two shells for the straight portions?

Comment: I'm not clear on the procedure. Do I make a revolution and then use another tool to change it?

Comment: Yes - look up flex in the help! I'm not at my computer to add details to this answer sorry.

Comment: I found a lot of less-than-useful information and blurry youtube videos. If you could update your answer with a video showing how you designed this I can follow the same process you did.

Comment: By "the help" I meant here: https://help.solidworks.com/2021/English/SolidWorks/sldworks/c_flex_overview.htm